# Why not just use self.view to switch view in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uiview, uikit

I have read many tutorials about switching views, seems so complicated for doing such a basic stuff why not just create a method in rootviewcontroller for modifying self.view ? I never saw that so this may be something rotten but I can't see why ?

Answer (score 2):

You think that switching views using separate view controllers is complicated?

It is possible to just use the root view and use code to change the view, but I promise you your application with become a spaghetti filled mess that is a major hassle to maintain.

You don't have to take my word for it though. Go ahead and try it out with your own app. You will soon find that you are spending your time writing tons of code to do the same thing that the current methodology allows you to do in about three lines.

Comment: @user310291: For a not-so-complex app your approach would definetly work, but it seems more like an experimental idea. The next logical step would be - why use UIKit at all? :) I agree with sosborn on this one.